# Add password protection to all applications screen in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

In short: Is it possible to allow user to view home screen and interact with Icons (placed by a technician) there, but to password protect access to *all applications* screen?

I am developing for an embedded device with Android 9. This solution allows me to choose *default application*, which is started on android boot, and leaving this application is password protected - a kiosk mode.

But for one integration with a 3rd party solution, we will need to have several applications accessible for the end-user. One possibility is to make this *crossroad* inside our *Main application*, but the configuration would be probably static and not easily adjustbale by entering a password and some drag-and-drop from all apps screen.

So I am trying to find out, if this behaviour is achievable on Android level, to have accessible idle/home screen and **password** protected access to all-apps screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement your own launcher. The "all-apps" screen is part of the launcher, and your own launcher can password-protect it.